# failed in push to heroku - can't find the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

I'm pushing my rails app to heroku and It fails and I don't know what is the problem, here's the heroku log, knowing that I'm still a beginner

```
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Your Gemfile lists the gem bootstrap-sass (= 3.3.7) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching rake 12.3.1
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Fetching minitest 5.10.3
       Installing minitest 5.10.3
       Installing rake 12.3.1
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.3
       Installing builder 3.2.3
       Fetching erubi 1.7.1
       Installing erubi 1.7.1
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.4
       Installing crass 1.0.4
       Fetching rack 2.0.5
       Installing rack 2.0.5
       Fetching nio4r 2.3.1
       Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.1
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.1
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching method_source 0.9.0
       Installing method_source 0.9.0
       Fetching thor 0.20.0
       Installing thor 0.20.0
       Fetching formtastic_i18n 0.6.0
       Installing formtastic_i18n 0.6.0
       Fetching kaminari-core 1.1.1
       Fetching arel 9.0.0
       Installing kaminari-core 1.1.1
       Installing arel 9.0.0
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Fetching ffi 1.9.25
       Fetching mimemagic 0.3.2
       Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
       Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
       Fetching bcrypt 3.1.12
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.12 with native extensions
       Fetching msgpack 1.2.4
       Installing msgpack 1.2.4 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using json 2.1.0
       Fetching mime-types-data 3.2018.0812
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2018.0812
       Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
       Installing multi_json 1.13.1
       Fetching pg 0.18.4
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Fetching puma 3.12.0
       Installing puma 3.12.0 with native extensions
       Fetching tilt 2.0.8
       Installing tilt 2.0.8
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
       Fetching i18n 0.9.5
       Installing i18n 0.9.5
       Fetching nokogiri 1.8.4
       Installing nokogiri 1.8.4 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.0
       Installing websocket-driver 0.7.0 with native extensions
       Fetching mail 2.7.0
       Installing mail 2.7.0
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.1.3
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.1.3
       Fetching uglifier 4.1.18
       Installing uglifier 4.1.18
       Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
       Installing rack-test 1.1.0
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching warden 1.2.7
       Installing warden 1.2.7
       Fetching marcel 0.3.2
       Installing marcel 0.3.2
       Fetching mime-types 3.2.2
       Installing mime-types 3.2.2
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Fetching bootsnap 1.3.1
       Installing bootsnap 1.3.1 with native extensions
       Fetching activesupport 5.2.1
       Installing activesupport 5.2.1
       Fetching faker 1.7.3
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing faker 1.7.3
       Fetching loofah 2.2.2
       Installing loofah 2.2.2
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.1
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing globalid 0.4.1
       Fetching arbre 1.1.1
       Installing arbre 1.1.1
       Fetching activemodel 5.2.1
       Installing activemodel 5.2.1
       Fetching jbuilder 2.7.0
       Fetching sass 3.5.7
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Installing jbuilder 2.7.0
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Installing sass 3.5.7
       Fetching activejob 5.2.1
       Installing activejob 5.2.1
       Fetching activerecord 5.2.1
       Installing activerecord 5.2.1
       Fetching carrierwave 0.11.2
       Installing carrierwave 0.11.2
       Fetching actionview 5.2.1
       Installing actionview 5.2.1
       Fetching actionpack 5.2.1
       Installing actionpack 5.2.1
       Fetching kaminari-actionview 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari-actionview 1.1.1
       Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Fetching kaminari-activerecord 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari-activerecord 1.1.1
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Fetching kaminari 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari 1.1.1
       Fetching actioncable 5.2.1
       Fetching actionmailer 5.2.1
       Installing actioncable 5.2.1
       Installing actionmailer 5.2.1
       Fetching railties 5.2.1
       Installing railties 5.2.1
       Fetching formtastic 3.1.5
       Installing formtastic 3.1.5
       Fetching has_scope 0.7.2
       Installing has_scope 0.7.2
       Fetching ransack 2.0.1
       Installing ransack 2.0.1
       Fetching activestorage 5.2.1
       Installing activestorage 5.2.1
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Fetching responders 2.4.0
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing responders 2.4.0
       Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Fetching rails 5.2.1
       Installing rails 5.2.1
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
       Fetching inherited_resources 1.9.0
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
       Installing inherited_resources 1.9.0
       Fetching devise 4.5.0
       Fetching activeadmin 1.3.1
       Installing activeadmin 1.3.1
       Installing devise 4.5.0
       Bundle complete! 29 Gemfile dependencies, 83 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from sass:

       Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.

       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811

       Bundle completed (80.77s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem bootstrap-sass (= 3.3.7) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.734693 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin-2f0c629fec336846acce347e83766ca452d7cd2476c4982b2754ee82f9ec07d2.css
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.735467 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin-2f0c629fec336846acce347e83766ca452d7cd2476c4982b2754ee82f9ec07d2.css.gz
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.736190 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow-15084d93c65c1964d7077700ea748bd2d70cfa2d4c19707c58a9c64e232dd442.gif
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.737492 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow_dark-7c43b8e0a5f8823875f49a093c9d7a6b374f885b6f9cc248ae9cd7e6e9b29034.gif
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.738714 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin/orderable-29374dbb55b0012d78a37c614d573bb3474f0779849b478a147d0f1845ca6617.png
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.922270 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin/print-cf99cbf27fb92065a9eacd28e6fad48fa72cadaf6e0918790e8d35b11d8f99f6.css
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:07.922488 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin/print-cf99cbf27fb92065a9eacd28e6fad48fa72cadaf6e0918790e8d35b11d8f99f6.css.gz
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:16.019597 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin-f23692a0f65604671f6920cdddfccfc6a2b48230d03d594e317a335f8f821854.js
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:16.020503 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/active_admin-f23692a0f65604671f6920cdddfccfc6a2b48230d03d594e317a335f8f821854.js.gz
       I, [2018-09-08T19:25:16.024346 #1679]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/public/assets/eseed-03cb614c50858ccb77604c8880c5e2e161a53bd3e4e1581d1b9db920771bcab9.jpg
       rake aborted!
       Uglifier::Error: Unexpected character '#'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_c75357820f68f58674096bc8758f9029/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Notes: tried to fix the uglifier by changing production.rb using this answer, but it's not working though
[Syntax error when deploying Rails app to Heroku: ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883113/syntax-error-when-deploying-rails-app-to-heroku-execjsruntimeerror-syntaxerr)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
remove the comment line which is start with "#" from any of your .js file
source of answer: [ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316650/execjsprogramerror-unexpected-character)

Answer (score 0):

You would use bundle update, to update the version of gem, run  `gem install bundler`
Your application must be up to date because is rely on gems that have deprecated features and about update gems 
see [here](http://You%20would%20use%20bundle%20update,%20to%20update%20the%20version%20of%20gem,%20run%20%20%60gem%20install%20bundler%60%20Your%20application%20must%20be%20up%20to%20date%20because%20is%20rely%20on%20gems%20that%20have%20deprecated%20features%20and%20about%20update%20gems%20%20see%20here%20https://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-update.1.html)